# Copy the same .py file into different folders

Tags: cmd, copy

I have a simple task which I want to perform in **cmd**. I have a python file named `Export_Excel.py` stored in `D:\Getting_Started_PyCharm\pyradiomics` which I want to copy in many directories.

More specifically I have 30 directories which are inside a folder called `NRRD` and they are called:

```
1_patient, 2_patient, ..., 30_patient
```

Is there a way to do this with a **for** loop and the **copy** function in cmd??

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
rem You should replace "" with NRRD's path in the file
set temppath=""
FOR /R %temppath% %%G in (.) DO (
 Pushd %%G
 copy D:\Getting_Started_PyCharm\pyradiomics\Export_Excel.py %%G
 Popd )
echo Copying is done.
```

Example for PUSHD and POPD

```
   C:\Program Files> PUSHD c:\utils
   C:\utils> PUSHD c:\Windows
   C:\Windows> 
   C:\Windows> POPD
   C:\utils> 
   C:\utils> POPD
   C:\Program Files>
```

This is the updated code:
 Save this file in notepad as forcopy.bat and run it from the folder.

```
set temppath=C:\Users\tommaso\Desktop\Lavoro\Zurich_Fellowship\Myocardial_Infarction_DICOM_Images_19_04 _Copia\NRRD
cd %temppath%
for /r %temppath% %%G IN (.) DO (
Pushd %%G
copy "C:\Users\tommaso\Desktop\Excel_Export.py" %%G
Popd
)
del Excel_Export.py
cls
Echo Copying is done
pause
rem //Pause is to pause the execution and wait until the user presses a key.//
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I will try that. Could you please explain me what the %%G, Pushd and Popd are for?

Thanks again!

Comment: PUSHD: Change the current directory/folder and store the previous folder/path for use by the POPD command. POPD: Change directory back to the path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD command.

Comment: %%G is the parameter of the for loop which receives the subfolders in this loop.

Comment: Hi again @AG_BOSS! Thanks a lot,

I moved my Export_Excel.py to my Desktop just for simplicity. I tried typing in cmd:


set temppath = C:\Users\tommaso\Desktop\Lavoro\Zurich_Fellowship\Myocardial_Infarction_DICOM_Images_19_04 _Copia\NRRD

for /r %temppath% %%G in (.) do (Pushd %%G copy C:\Users\tommaso\Desktop\Excel.Export.py %%G Popd)


but it told me "%%G not expected". Am I missing something? Thanks again

Comment: Moreover, what's the purpose of (.) ? Thanks again!

Comment: we don't need any parameters for IN so we leave it as it is : IN (.)

Comment: Ok thanks. I typed the code (starting from: for /r....) in Notepad and then saved it as .cmd in the Desktop. When double-click on it, it opens the cmd and iterates very quickly (I can't read what it outputs) and then closes itself, but the file was not copied....what could I try?
Thanks again

Comment: wait did you type set temppath?

Comment: Hi again!
I typed your exact code (except from cd temppath that was throwing an error). I typed cd C:\Users\tommaso\Desktop\Lavoro\Zurich_Fellowship\Myocardial_Infarction_DICOM_Images_19_04_Copia\NRRD instead.
It seemed to work fine since it arrived at the "pause" command. So I entered a random character to continue but the file has not been saved in any of the folder :(

Comment: Sorry, it was cd %temppath%

Comment: And also instead of {} i had to put (). Sorry for the inconvenience. Just check the edit once again.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found a python alternative which is even easier:

```
import os
from shutil import copy

path_to_file = "/.../.../Export_Excel.py"

path_destination_folder = "/.../.../NRRD/"

for sub_folders in os.listdir(path_destination_folder):
    copy(path_to_file, os.path.join(path_destination_folder, sub_folders))
```